# OpenCV findcontours() not able to detect contours

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following image from which I am trying to read the numbers which are in [MICR E-13B font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition#/media/File:MICR_char.svg).
[image: Recognize numbers]
I am using template matching from OpenCV to find the numbers corresponding to the image.So,the problem in broken down into 3 steps:
**Step 1:** To detect the MICR E-13B font which is done easily using findcontours() and detecting a rectangle to achieve the following output.
[image]
**Step 2:** In step 2, we go to get each of the contours (which contain MICR E-13B font) from above so that they can be separated for further individual breaking of digits.
**Step 3:** `This is where the error occurs.` Obtaining above output, the task is now to break down the group of digits into single digit so that they can be matched using template matching in OpenCV. But when I apply findcontour method and proceed with detecting boundRect for each contour I don't get any bounding rectangle.
Following is the code for various steps:
**Step 1:**

```
# apply a tophat (whitehat) morphological operator to find light
# regions against a dark background
tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, rectKernel)

# compute the Scharr gradient of the tophat image, then scale
# the rest back into the range [0, 255]
gradX = cv2.Sobel(tophat, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0,
    ksize=-1)
gradX = np.absolute(gradX)
(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(gradX), np.max(gradX))
gradX = (255 * ((gradX - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal)))
gradX = gradX.astype("uint8")

# apply a closing operation using the rectangular kernel to help
# cloes gaps in between credit card number digits, then apply
# Otsu's thresholding method to binarize the image
gradX = cv2.morphologyEx(gradX, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rectKernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gradX, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply a second closing operation to the binary image, again
# to help close gaps between credit card number regions
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, sqKernel)

thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations = 3)
clone = np.dstack([thresh.copy()] * 3
# find contours in the thresholded image, then initialize the
# list of digit locations
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
locs = []

# loop over the contours
for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if i<=3:   #First 4 images are the MICR font
        cv2.rectangle(clone, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 1) #color is set to blue but it shows white (error?)
        locs.append((x, y, w, h))
```

**Step 2:**

```
locs = sorted(locs, key=lambda x:x[0])
output = []
print (locs)

for (i, (gX, gY, gW, gH)) in enumerate(locs):
    if i==0:
        group = gray[gY:gY+gH, gX:gX+gW]
        cv2.rectangle(gray, (gX, gY), (gX+gW, gY+gH), (255,0,0), 1)
        group = cv2.threshold(group, 0, 255,
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

         # re-initialize the clone image so we can draw on it again
         clone = np.dstack([group.copy()]*3)
         cv2.rectangle(clone, (gX, gY), (gX+gW, gY+gH), (255,0,0), 1)
         cv2.imshow('Image5', clone)
         cv2.waitKey()
```

**Error Output**: The green mask doesn't bound rectangles correctly.
[image]

**Step 3:**

```
# detect the contours of each individual digit in the group,
# then sort the digit contours from left to right
digitCnts = cv2.findContours(group.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
digitCnts = digitCnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else digitCnts[1]
cv2.drawContours(clone, digitCnts, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
cv2.imshow('Image6', clone)
cv2.waitKey()
for c in digitCnts:
    # compute the bounding box of the individual digit, extract
    # the digit, and resize it to have the same fixed size as
    # the reference MICR images
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    print (x, y, x+w, y+h)
    cv2.rectangle(clone, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 3)
    cv2.imshow('Image7', clone) 
    cv2.waitKey()
```

**Error Output**:
[image]

This is where the error arises as it is supposed to split the the output of step 2 into individual digits like "9", "5" and so on which can be passed onto template matching. But the length of contours comes to be 11 and also there are no bounding boxes drawn by the last step to the previous output to indicate separate digits.

Comment: foreground should be white, and background should be black. Invert the image (`255 - image`) before calling `findContours`. Also the image should be only B/W, but I see some gray areas. Be sure to create a binary mask!

Comment: @Miki, I edited the code and images so as to make foreground white and background black. But the output after detecting all MICR digits and applying `findContours` gives error `green colored mask` and also the `red colored mask` for further separation of digits using above contours has also error.